# Ackermann function and $f_\omega$

Tags: big-numbers, ackermann-function

The Wikipedia page of [Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) states that Ackermann function is "roughly comparable" to $f_\omega$ in [fast-growing hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy).

Is there some standard way to make the "roughly comparable" to more precise form? I would like to understand the claim better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I discuss this in some detail in my paper

> Andres E. Caicedo, [Regressive functions on pairs](http://andrescaicedo.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/regressivepairs.pdf), European Journal of Combinatorics, **31 (3)**, (2010), 803–812. [MR2587031 (2011e:05270)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2587031),

but the results are more or less folklore, so I do not include details there (but they are not hard). Anyway, as mentioned in section 2, say that a function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is *(precisely) of Ackermannian growth* iff there are constants $c,C>0$ such that for all but finitely many $m$, we have $$f_\omega(cm)\le f(m)\le f_\omega(Cm). $$
Similarly, say that a function's rate of growth is like that of the $n$th level of the Ackermann hierarchy iff there are constants $c,C>0$ such that for all but finitely many $m$, we have $$A_n(cm)\le f(m)\le A_n(Cm).$$ 
(Here, $A_n(m)=A(n,m)$.)

This is similar to the notion of *Ackermannic functions*, in the sense defined in the book **Ramsey theory** by Graham, Rothschild, and Spencer (Section 2.7), which is probably the most easily available reference that discusses related matters.

We have:

> **Lemma.** $1.$ For all $n$, $A_n <A_{n+1}$ (pointwise) and $f_n<^∗f_{n+1}$ (that is, in the sense of eventual domination: From some point on). In fact, for any $C>0$ and almost all $m$, $A_n(Cm)< A_{n+1}(m)$ for $n>0$, and $f_n(Cm)<f_{n+1}(m)$ for all $n$.
>
> $2.$ For all $n>0$, $A_{n+1}<^∗f_n$ and $f_n(m)<A_{n+1}(cm)$ for some constant $c=c_n$, and all $m$.
>
> $3.$ $f_\omega$ and $\mathrm{Ack}$, (the diagonal function, $\mathrm{Ack}(n)=A_n(n)$) are of Ackermannian growth.
>
> $4.$ If $f$ is of Ackermannian growth, it eventually dominates each primitive recursive function. In particular, it eventually dominates each $f_n$.
>
> $5.$ If $f$ is of Ackermannian growth, then it is eventually dominated by $f_{\omega+1}$.
>
> $6.$ There is a function $f$ that eventually dominates each $f_n$ and is eventually dominated by $f_{\omega +1}$, but is not of Ackermannian growth.
>
> $7.$ If $g,h$ are strictly increasing primitive recursive functions, and $f$ is of Ackermannian growth, then $g\circ f$ is of Ackermannian growth, and $f\circ h<^* f_{\omega+1}$.

(Most of the items in this list can be significantly strengthened.) One question the above does not address is whether functions that eventually dominate all primitive recursive functions are of Ackermannian growth or higher. This is actually not the case, and is discussed at length in the paper

> Harold Simmons. *The Ackermann functions are not optimal but by how much?*, J. Symbolic Logic, **75 (1)**, (2010), 289–313. [MR2605895 (2011j:03099)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2605895).

The reason why the comparison came about is that in my paper I identified a natural combinatorial problem that gives us a function of Ackermannian growth. This may well be the first example of such a thing. The problem came from an earlier [result](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=870685) of Kanamori and McAloon in Ramsey theory that is true but nor provable in Peano Arithmetic. The result depends on a parameter $k$, and the case $k=2$ is the one giving rise to the Ackermannian function.

Comment: Oh, that's nice. If possible, please email me a copy of your thesis once it is done.

Comment: I had a strange flashback of your comment about e-mailing the thesis (I had the previous account deleted). If you are still interested I would be happy to send you a pdf copy.

Comment: Yes, please, that would be great! Thank you! My email account can be found from the website listed on my profile.

Comment: (@FFF Not sure if you saw my previous reply, I forgot to @-notify you. Again, thanks!)

Comment: I e-mailed You a copy on Sunday but I guess You did not receive that. It was to the umich-address (from gmail). I will resend it from my work mail to both or Your addresses. If there still no success I'll check if I have hard copies left :)

Comment: If I may so mention, if you say that $$g(n)\in f_\alpha(n)\iff\left(\exists(0<N,0<c<C)\forall(n>N)\implies f_\alpha(cn)\le g(n)\le f_\alpha(Cn)\right)$$then you will find there are many functions such that $g(n)\notin f_\alpha(n)$ for any $n$, which is a disadvantage if you want to compare any computable function to the fast growing hierarchy.  See my answer for an alternative definition that encompasses all computable functions

Answer (score 4):

Generally, when one compares functions to the fast growing hierarchy, we say that a function $g(n)$ grows at $f_\alpha(n)$ if $g(n)$ grows faster than $f_\beta(n)$ for every $\beta<\alpha$ and $g(n)$ grows slower than $f_\alpha^k(n)$ for a fixed $k$.  For functions/notations that come with multiple arguments, we diagonalize, for example,

$$g(n)=\chi(n,n,n,\dots,n)$$

Basically, replace every argument of the function with $n$ and call that $g(n)$.

Formally, we may define

$$g(n)\in f_\alpha(n)\iff\exists k\in\mathbb N\forall\beta<\alpha\exists0<N\forall n>N\text{ s.t. }g(n)>f_\beta(n)\land g(n)<f_\alpha^k(n)$$

Particularly here, all one needs to show is that

$$f_k(n)\ll A(n,n)\ll f_\omega(n)$$

Under this definition, you will find that every eventually monotonically increasing function can find a place on the fast growing hierarchy, and that there are simple properties, for example:

$$g(n)\in f_\alpha(n)\implies\begin{cases}g^k(n)\in f_\alpha(n)\\g^n(n)\in f_{\alpha+1}(n)\end{cases}$$

So repeatedly nesting Ackermann functions a fixed amount of times does not take you further down the fast growing hierarchy, instead, you need to nest the function a non-constant (and increasing) amount of times.